# Rails clone or hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey,
  i need to use current_user model in order to perform some calculations inside a function. Inside the function i need to do something like current_user.name = 'whatever', thus changing the current value of name.

However, i want that change to be local, only done inside that function. Since Rails uses objects though, it's a problem. So i'm thinking, what is the best thing to do ?

Maybe clone current_user to a new object and use that inside the function ? This seems expensive.
Or maybe creating a hash out of a model ? And if i do that, the actual model will not be changed ?

EDIT: It seems that hash works, but there is no type associated with it, so if i do something like :

```
@attacker = current_user.attributes
```

then, to use it, i have to specify to_s like (else i get a nil error for some reason):

@attacker[:name].to_s = 'whatever'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters?

```
def my_f(name)
  new_name = "lorem" + name
  return new_name
end
```

Somewhere in your controller:

```
loremized_name = my_f(current_user.name)
```

Comment: hmm, i wouldn't want to create virtual attributes for every possible attribute of my model that needs to be changed. Don't you think it can be done with hashes ?

Comment: It's a plain variable. Since you need `to perform some calculations inside a function` and you `want that change to be local, only done inside that function` its safe to use a variable within the scope of your function. You can return that variable or let it die inside your function as you please. No virtual attribute required.

Comment: you are right, that is also an option, i also tried hashes and they work ok as well now. It seems that the variable solution is less expensive though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all of the logic in your model, the easiest way would be to simply clone it:

```
def local_function
  user = current_user.clone
  # Perform some calculations on user here
end
```

Comment: yeap, this was what i was doing, but i abandoned it and used variables, as lbz mentioned above. I don't really like cloning objects if there's a real urgency.